# Firestore listeners stops listening when the user is signed out and re-signed in

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Minimum reproducible code**

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  final col = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('foo');
  col.doc('bar').snapshots().listen((event) {
    print('Data = ${event.data()}');
  });
}
  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously(),
          child: Text('Sign in'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
          child: Text('Sign out'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

My security rules are:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

When I sign out and sign in again, my listener stops listening. Is this by design? Should I again setup my listener each time there's a sign out event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you're seeing is the expected behavior.

Since your security rules require that there is a signed in user to read the data, signing out the current user cancels any existing listeners (as they no longer meet the requirement).

You will have to (re)attach listeners for the new user once their sign in is completed.